# Using file output node results in 2 images being saved

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, render-layers, render-passes

I am rendering denoised render passes using the openEXR Multilayer format.
(The default output does not save the denoised passes)

So right now I take each pass and plug it into a denoise node. And then plug those into the file output node.
When I hit render it creates the image with the denoised passes.

The problem is that it also saves the "original" render output from the "Output path" in the render properties panel.

Is there a way to avoid this? I only want the output from the file output node.